# How to tag people in SharePoint Blog site

Tags: user-profile, blog, tagging

For now we are using "out of the box" feature, we go to persons profile site, copy his url and create simple link.

I would like to accomplish next:

When writing a Blog post I would like to have button which opens dialog with people picker control, OK and Cancel buttons. Next, I would write user name of person which I want to tag and when OK is clicked it should add:

```
<a href="http://intranet.contoso.com/mysite/personal/Person.aspx?accountname=domain\username">Full Name</a>
```

which would enable blog readers to click on person's name and see full profile of mentioned person.

and it would be great if there is an option which would insert Lync status too, like in usual SharePoint lists, column "Modified By" or "Created By".

I know how to make custom dialog box and return it's value back to post, what I'm curious about is C# code which would do the work of finding users information and Lync status.

Thanks.